# Can I use Java 8 on IBM's Bluemix Application Platform

Tags: java-8, ibm-cloud

I would like to use Java 8 features in Bluemix standalone java application, is this supported by default or do I need to alter some configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask for Java 8 with the default liberty buildpack by setting the following environment variable:

```
$ cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK "version: 1.8.+"
```

See [Customizing the JRE](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#customizingjre) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's required, but I wouldn't leave such matters to the defaults. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#configuration-and-extension